# Js append and remove specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have div for each user appended to onlineusers and when specific user leave i want to delete appended div of him

im adding online users this way:

```
 for(var i=0;i < data.length; i++) {

         $('#onlineusers').append('<div class="user" data-id="' + data[i].id + '"><span>' + data[i].jmeno + '</span></div>');
      }
```

for example i want to remove user with data-id 60
so i tried

```
 $('#onlineusers').remove('<div class="user" data-id="60"></div>');
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

You call `remove()` on the jQuery collection you want to remove, not the parent. You can use the attribute selector to do so:

```
$('div.user[data-id=60]').remove();
```

You could also use `filter()` instead of filtering your selector, say if you wanted to change the `.user` elements prior to removing one with a specific `data-id`:

```
$('div.user').filter('[data-id=60]').remove()
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KRKrL/)

Comment: +1 *"...on the selector..."* On the jQuery set you've created *using* that selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

```
$('.user[data-id="60"]').remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`for(var i=0;i < data.length; i++) {

         $('#onlineusers').append('<div class="user" data-id="' + data[i].id + '"><span>' + data[i].jmeno + '</span></div>');
      }`
```

i would change this to this .

```
`for(var i=0;i < data.length; i++) {

         $('#onlineusers').append('<div class="user" id="' online+ data[i].id + '"><span>' + data[i].jmeno + '</span></div>');
      }`

 `$('#online60').remove();`
```